# Scrapy not working with return and yield together

Tags: python, scrapy

This is my code

```
def parse(self, response):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.body)
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    sites = hxs.select('//div[@class="row"]')
    items = []

    for site in sites[:5]:
        item = TestItem()
        item['username'] = "test5"
        request =  Request("http://www.example.org/profile.php",  callback = self.parseUserProfile)
        request.meta['item'] = item
        **yield item**

    mylinks= soup.find_all("a", text="Next")
    if mylinks:
        nextlink = mylinks[0].get('href')
        yield Request(urljoin(response.url, nextlink), callback=self.parse)

def parseUserProfile(self, response):
    item = response.meta['item']
    item['image_urls'] = "test3"
    return item
```

Now my above works but with that i am not getting value of `item['image_urls'] = "test3"`

It is coming as null

Now if use  `return request` instead of `yield item`

Then get error that `cannot use return with generator`

If i remove this line

`yield Request(urljoin(response.url, nextlink), callback=self.parse)`
Then my code works fine and i can get `image_urls` but then i canot follow the links

So is there any way so that i can use `return request` and `yield together` so that i get the item_urls

Comment: If you use `yield` you make your function a generator, which is what your error is telling you. Where is `item` defined in `parseUserProfile`? Is it a class variable.

Comment: @Blender I forgot to add here, i am getting from meta response. so what should i do to solve my problem. i have added in my question

Comment: For my Scrapy application, I've always only used the `yield` statement in my callback functions and everything works fine. Have you tried to replace `return item` by `yield item` in `parseUserProfile`?

Comment: I tried removing `yield item` from parse and replace return item by `yield item` in `parseUserProfile` , then nothing gets saved in database. spider runs fine but scrapy dont get any items

Comment: That's a python error about generators - you cannot both yield and return items (or requests). Pick one, either use generators or don't. You can return any python sequence from a callback in scrapy. As for your spider, it sounds like you want to yield requests from parse, that have their callback set to self.parseUserProfile (not self.parse) and that callback completes the data in the item.

Comment: @Shane I am not good at python , is there any way we can make some chnage and i can solve my problem

Answer (score 2):

I don't really understand your issue, but i see one problem in your code:

```
def parseUserProfile(self, response):
    item = response.meta['item']
    item['image_urls'] = "test3"
    return item
```

Parse callbacks return values should be sequences, so you should do `return [item]` or convert your callback into a generator:

```
def parseUserProfile(self, response):
    item = response.meta['item']
    item['image_urls'] = "test3"
    yield item
```

Comment: I have tried evrything , that yield item is also working but my problem is that my logic of returning `items` and getting the nextlink to follow is in same function. so either i should `return item` which is parsed on page or i should return the `request` for crawling the next links. IN crawlspider the rules thing automatically folows the link links which they get from link extractor but in basespider i have to manually get the links and follow them manually. this is where i am in a problem

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have a mechanical error. Instead of:

```
for site in sites[:5]:
    item = TestItem()
    item['username'] = "test5"
    request =  Request("http://www.example.org/profile.php",  callback = self.parseUserProfile)
    request.meta['item'] = item
    **yield item**
```

You need:

```
for site in sites[:5]:
    item = TestItem()
    item['username'] = "test5"
    request =  Request("http://www.example.org/profile.php",  callback = self.parseUserProfile)
    request.meta['item'] = item
    yield request
```

Comment: with that i am not getting any items returned by scrapy. i just get one entry in database. i don't get any error and crawler runs ok but scrapy does not get any items beside the first item. we are very close to solve this as i don't get any error. i even tried by puting yield item in parseuserprofile but again it don't return any items

Comment: The only thing which returns the item properly is `return request` there but with that i can't use the second yield.

Comment: and in `parseUserProfile` put `yield item`

Comment: I already tried that but i don't get any items returned by that.

Comment: You have to debug. Put some prints or `pdb.set_trace` in callbacks to see if anything is called at all.