# How to yield url with orders to let scrapy crawl

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

here is my code:

```
def parse(self, response):  
    selector = Selector(response)
    sites = selector.xpath("//h3[@class='r']/a/@href")
    for index, site in enumerate(sites):
        url =  result.group(1) 
        print url
        yield Request(url = site.extract(),callback = self.parsedetail)

def parsedetail(self,response):
    print response.url
    ...
    obj = Store.objects.filter(id=store_obj.id,add__isnull=True)
    if obj:
    obj.update(add=add)
```

in `def parse`
scarpy will get urls from google
the url output like:

```
www.test.com
www.hahaha.com
www.apple.com
www.rest.com
```

but when it yield to `def parsedetail`
the  url is not with order maybe it will become :

```
www.rest.com
www.test.com
www.hahaha.com
www.apple.com
```

is there any way I can let the yield url with order to send to `def parsedetail` ?
Because I need to crawl  `www.test.com` first.(the data the top url provide in google search is more correctly)
if there is no data in it.
I will go next url until update the empty field .(`www.hahaha.com` ,`www.apple.com`,`www.rest.com`)
Please guide me thank you!

Answer (score 2):

By default, the order which the Scrapy requests are scheduled and sent is not defined. But, you can control it using [`priority` keyword argument](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Request):

> priority (int) – the priority of this request (defaults to 0). The
>   priority is used by the scheduler to define the order used to process
>   requests. Requests with a higher priority value will execute earlier.
>   Negative values are allowed in order to indicate relatively
>   low-priority.

---

You can also make the crawling *synchronous* by passing around the `callstack` inside the `meta` dictionary, as an example see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25571270/771848).