# Python scraping using scrapy

Tags: python-2.7, web-scraping, web-crawler, scrapy

So, I have seen the tutorials of how to use scrapy and now I can visit links in a given page. But what I want to do is that given a page I want to collect its data (metadata and summary) also I want to visit links in that page and collect their data. This is my code so far (not collected data yet)

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.http import Request
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.selector import Selector
#from scrapy.item import SpideyItem

class spidey (CrawlSpider):
    name = "spidey"
    allowed_domains = ["wikipedia.org"]
    start_urls = ["http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_of_Thrones"]

    rules = (

        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths=('//div[@class="nw-  body"]//a/@href'))),
    Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/",)), callback = 'parse_item'),

    )

def parse_item(self, response):
    sel = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    print sel.xpath('//h1[@class="firstHeading"]/span/text()').extract()
```

So after this I want to collect data of initial page and data present in the links that I visit. I am new into web spiders, any pointer is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your question is exactly but if you are asking how to collect data from multiple pages and save it into one item...this is your answer:

https://github.com/darkrho/scrapy-inline-requests

Also if you don't want to do it in inline way, you can always store your item in request.meta and send it in a request with a callback to a function that extracts data from the page.

Check this answer: [How can i use multiple requests and pass items in between them in scrapy python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13910357/how-can-i-use-multiple-requests-and-pass-items-in-between-them-in-scrapy-python)