# Scrapy: scrape item fields from different pages

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm trying to get item fields info from different pages using scrapy.

What I am trying to do:

1. main_url > scrape all links from this page > go to each link
2. from each link > scrape info, put info in items list and go to another link
3. from another link > scrape info and put info in the same items list
4. Go to next each link...repeat steps 2 - 4

when all links are done go to next page and repeat steps 1 - 3

I found some information from below but, I still can't get the results I want:

[How can i use multiple requests and pass items in between them in scrapy python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13910357/how-can-i-use-multiple-requests-and-pass-items-in-between-them-in-scrapy-python)

http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#topics-request-response-ref-request-callback-arguments

**Goal:** to get the below layout results

[image]

**What I've done is below**

My item class

```
from scrapy.item import Item, Field

class myItems(Item):
    info1 = Field()
    info2 = Field()
    info3 = Field()
    info4 = Field()
```

My spider class

```
from scrapy.http import Request
from myProject.items import myItems

class mySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'spider1'
    start_urls = ['main_link']

    def parse(self, response):
        items = []

        list1 = response.xpath().extract() #extract all info from here
        list2 = response.xpath().extract() #extract all info from here
        for i,j in zip(list1, list2):
            link1 = 'http...' + i
            request = Request(link1, self.parseInfo1, dont_filter =True)
            request.meta['item'] = items
            yield request

            link2 = 'https...' + j
            request = Request(link2, self.parseInfo2, meta={'item':items}, dont_filter = True)

            # Code for crawling to next page 


    def parseInfo1(self, response):
        item = myItems()
        items = response.meta['item']
        item[info1] = response.xpath().extract()
        item[info2] = response.xpath().extract()
        items.append(item)
        return items

    def parseInfo2(self, response):
        item = myItems()
        items = response.meta['item']
        item[info3] = response.xpath().extract()
        item[info4] = response.xpath().extract()
        items.append(item)
        return items
```

I executed the spider by typing this on the terminal:

```
> scrapy crawl spider1 -o filename.csv -t csv
```

I got the results for all the fields, but they are not in the right order. My csv file looks like this:

[image]

Does anyone know how to get the results like in my "Goal" above? 
I appreciate the help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I found my mistake. I instantiated myItems class twice, which resulted in 2 new objects and gave the results that I got.